# DynamoDB backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking into how I can backup DynamoDB using a Lambda function. My goal is to:

1. Backup a database.
2. Store the backup in an other account.

I've managed to do the first using boto3 and the `create_backup()` call. The second part is where I am stuck at. I cannot find a way to download the backup and store it elsewhere.

I've also looked into `export_table_to_point_in_time()` but these exports cannot be used to restore a table from what I see.

Is it possible in any way to create a backup from a table and store it in a different account, preferably using a Lambda function?

Comment: Can you please add your backing up code?

Comment: And what do you mean by "download" the backup? Can you achieve what you want via the console? I might be wrong but I'm 99% sure you can't "download" a DynamoDB backup via the normal backup function.

Comment: However I do know and have used the backup to S3 option which will export it as DDB marshalled JSON - you could perform a backup to S3 (if the API calls exist), then make your Lambda copy the JSON to another account, and then (if the API calls exist) restore a table from the backup (again, I'm being theoretical, not really sure if you can recreate a table from the JSON but this might help)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary looks to me that Boto3 does not have that API call https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html

Comment: Can you even do what you want via the console? If you can't do it via the console, I can't see how you could automate it.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary you mentioned you exported to S3 using the CLI I am guessing, what call was that? I find it bizarre that it's that difficult to export a backup. What if you wanted to store it offline for safety...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [AWS Backup](https://aws.amazon.com/backup) service.

It supports backups for EC2, EBS, RDS, Dynamo, S3 (preview) and more.
Using AWS Backup you can:

- Schedule periodic or future backups
- Set up schedules and retention policies for your backups
- Centralize and automate data protection across AWS services
- Restore the backup at any time
- Apply policies to backups (e.g. restrict backup deletion)
- Set up cross-account backup

In order to [restore a backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Restore.Tutorial.html), you select the backup and enter the name of the table or a new name if you want to create a new table:

[image: Restore a backup]

Answer (score 1):

**To Export**

Go to “Exports and streams” tab in the DynamoDB table page

Click on “Export to S3” button

Select the S3 bucket where you want to export

You have two choices here.

1. You can choose the different AWS account while selecting the S3 bucket and give permissions according to that
   [image]
2. You can export to an S3 bucket present in the current account and enable CRR (Cross Region Replication) to replicate the objects to another account

**To Restore**

Choose backups section in DynamoDB console

In the list of backups, choose the backup and click Restore

Enter the new table name to restore

You can also exclude secondary indexes from being created on the new restored table. In addition, you can specify a different encryption mode.

Comment: This looks like the `export_table_to_point_in_time()` solution. Just missing one more detail before marking this as the solution. How would one use the exported data in a restore process? Like, how can I import it back into DynamoDB?